# how to make card not stretch when the windows is halfed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

another problem with my code is that my card is somehow stretch when i halfed the window.

[image: this is when window in halfed]

[image: this is when window is full]

this is my html

```
<div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto">
                        <section class="blog_w3ls" id="connected">
                            <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- blog grid -->
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
                                    <div class="med-blog">
                                        <div class="blog-header">
                                            <a href="blog1.html">
                                                <img class="img-fluid" src="image/merah.png" alt="image">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="blog-body bg-wh p-4">
                                            <a href="blog1.html" class="blog-title">Dictum porta auris magna umgtdd fos</a>
                                            <p>Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum portaout auris blandita. Nulla viverra pharetra
                                                se.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- //blog grid -->
                                <!-- blog grid -->
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
                                    <div class="med-blog">
                                        <div class="blog-header">
                                            <a href="blog2.html">
                                                <img class="img-fluid" src="image/merah.png" alt="image">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="blog-body bg-wh p-4">
                                            <a href="blog2.html" class="blog-title">Quis autem vel eum iure reprehdd ende</a>
                                            <p>Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum portaout auris blandita. Nulla viverra pharetra
                                                se.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- //blog grid -->
                                <!-- blog grid -->
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
                                    <div class="med-blog">
                                        <div class="blog-header">
                                            <a href="blog4.html">
                                                <img class="img-fluid" src="image/merah.png" alt="image">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="blog-body bg-wh p-4">
                                            <a href="blog4.html" class="blog-title">Suscipit labo iosam nisi ut aliquid</a>
                                            <p>Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum portaout auris blandita. Nulla viverra pharetra
                                                se.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- //blog grid -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
```

this is for css

```
.blog-body{
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

a.blog-title {
    color: orange;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 12px 0 16px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    text-align: center;
}

.blog-body span {
    color: #636363;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: block;
}
```

well i just need to make the card look the same as the one with the window is full but i already try playing with min-width that end up messed up everything

Comment: as the divs get thinner... you'd have to adjust the size of the fonts, else it would always be thin and tall - something like `.blog-body{ border:1px solid red; }
.blog-body .blog-title { font-size:1.5vw !important; }
.blog-body p  { font-size:1vw !important; }`

Comment: thanks for the answer its better now, anyway is there a way that the size of the card and map is always the same even when the window is resize?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the size of the font and padding of the boxes as you resize the browser window. For fix height you can consider using Cards with `class="h-100"`.

```css
a.blog-title {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 12px 0 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 1.2vw;
  /* using view width as font size parameter */
}

.card-body p {
  font-size: .9vw;
}

@media(max-width: 980px) {
  a.blog-title {
    color: orange;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .card-body {
    padding: 20px;
    /* You can change it into pixels here for mobile devices */
  }
  .card-body p {
    font-size: 14px;
    /* You can change it into pixels here for mobile devices */
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto">
  <section class="blog_w3ls" id="connected">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="image">
            <div class="card-body">
              <a href="blog1.html" class="blog-title">Dictum porta auris magna umgtdd fos</a>
              <p class="card-text">Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum portaout auris blandita. Nulla viverra pharetra se.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="image">
            <div class="card-body">
              <a href="blog1.html" class="blog-title">Quis autem vel eum iure reprehdd ende</a>
              <p class="card-text">Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum portaout auris blandita. Nulla viverra pharetra se.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" alt="image">
            <div class="card-body">
              <a href="blog1.html" class="blog-title">Suscipit labo iosam nisi ut aliquid</a>
              <p class="card-text">Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum portaout auris blandita. Nulla viverra pharetra se.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: my first comment told me to change the font to but it make my text unreadable on mobile, is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

No need to play with any css code, ***Bootstrap***  will help you out!
just try to paste that HTML code;

```
<div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto">
                    <section class="blog_w3ls" id="connected">
                        <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- blog grid -->
                            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 mt-4">
                                <div class="med-blog">
                                    <div class="blog-header">
                                        <a href="blog1.html">
                                            <img class="img-fluid" src="image/merah.png" alt="image">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="blog-body bg-wh p-4">
                                        <a href="blog1.html" class="blog-title">Dictum porta auris magna umgtdd fos</a>
                                        <p>Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum portaout auris blandita. Nulla viverra pharetra
                                            se.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- //blog grid -->
                            <!-- blog grid -->
                            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 mt-4">
                                <div class="med-blog">
                                    <div class="blog-header">
                                        <a href="blog2.html">
                                            <img class="img-fluid" src="image/merah.png" alt="image">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="blog-body bg-wh p-4">
                                        <a href="blog2.html" class="blog-title">Quis autem vel eum iure reprehdd ende</a>
                                        <p>Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum portaout auris blandita. Nulla viverra pharetra
                                            se.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- //blog grid -->
                            <!-- blog grid -->
                            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 mt-4">
                                <div class="med-blog">
                                    <div class="blog-header">
                                        <a href="blog4.html">
                                            <img class="img-fluid" src="image/merah.png" alt="image">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="blog-body bg-wh p-4">
                                        <a href="blog4.html" class="blog-title">Suscipit labo iosam nisi ut aliquid</a>
                                        <p>Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum portaout auris blandita. Nulla viverra pharetra
                                            se.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- //blog grid -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
```